# What is the correct way to designate the last character of a word in a DLB trie?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, trie

In my class, we have reviewed and are working on a project utilizing the De La Briandais Trie data structure to implement a dictionary.  I understand the data structure and what needs to be done to implement it.  However, I'm receiving conflicting approaches to denote the end of a valid word in my DLB.

On one hand, it was stated that we should use an ASCII character not used in words to denote that the word is complete, such as '^'.  I thought that this would be another node off of the last character of the word.  For example, "STACK" would be a linked list similar to (excuse this depiction):

```
[ROOT] -- [S] -- [T] -- [A] -- [C] -- [K] -- [^]
```

However, my TA stated that we should use a flag (boolean or integer) to denote the end of the word.  The integer could also be used to represent the frequency the word is found or used.  This is how it would appear with the `int` flag:

```
[ROOT] -- [S 0] -- [T 0] -- [A 0] -- [C 0] -- [K 1]
```

Each time the word was found, the integer of the final node would increment.

I would like to hear which is the most correct, universally accepted approach, or a marriage of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way will work, and there isn't a particular preference. If you include the flag, then every node in the trie has to include extra space for the flag. This could be a memory issue. But if you use a terminal node, there is an extra node for every word, and an extra transition when locating a word.

In practice, the memory difference is negligible. The extra transition per word when you use a terminal node is, at most, almost undetectable in performance analysis, and can be removed altogether with optimization.

In other words, use whichever you prefer.

Comment: Good explanation.  Good to know that both are viable options.  Also good to know that we aren't getting conflicting approaches during the teaching.